# Where is the log_daemon_msg?

Tags: shell-script, init-script

So this is my little `sh`script (my_init_script.sh) located in `/etc/init.d/`

```
#!/bin/sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

NAME=my_script_for_auto_update
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid


#PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

start() 
{
    start-stop-daemon -S -o -q -m -x -p $PIDFILE /home/ed/start_up_job/test_sort.sh 
    # log_daemon_msg "Started update"
}

stop() {
  start_stop-daemon -K -o -q -m -x -p $PIDFILE /home/ed/start_up_job/test_sort.sh
   # log_daemon_msg "Stopped update"
}

case "$1" in
    start)
      start
        ;;
    stop|force-stop)
      stop
        ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|restart|stop}"
esac    


exit 0
```

When I try to start the init script (`$ ./my_init_script.sh start`) the output yields

```
Try 'start-stop-daemon --help' for more information.
```

**Q:** Why is this error (still) present? Or is there a way to rewrite my code to bypass this error?

Comment: I think you are missing . /path/init-functions under #!/bin/bash

Comment: @tailezin is that path correct for all machines, or does it change from machine to machine?

Comment: I put "path" there. I think it should be . /lib/lsb/init-functions as of [this](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptfunc.html). But there are distributions that this is not the path.

Comment: @taliezin is there a way of 'definately' finding it, ie something like `pwd`, also to reconfirm it would `. /lib/lsb/init-functions`

Comment: you can see in your other init scripts.

Comment: @taliezin still can't get it to work... :/ what else would you recommend? (I am fairly new to programming - any help/advice you give will be highly appreciated)

Comment: This is a good example: [http://people.skolelinux.org/pere/blog/Debian_init_d_boot_script_example_for_rsyslog.html](http://people.skolelinux.org/pere/blog/Debian_init_d_boot_script_example_for_rsyslog.html).  Also if you still have errors about log_daemon_msg you can just remove it with echo "message".

Comment: @taliezin I've further updated my code. I've tried a combination of things seen from various websites, and didn't work - I am pulling out my hair! last error is "`Try 'start-stop-daemon --help' for more information.`" and by looking at it, I don't think I am doing _anything_ incorrect!!

Comment: change starting to: start-stop-daemon -S -o -q -m -p $PIDFILE -x /root/t/test_sort.sh You have to see options in man page and to apply properly.. Also you have a typo in stopping service - change  start_stop-daemon to start-stop-daemon.

Comment: @taliezin, it works! Thanks! But it works in the foreground, I was under the impression daemons work in the background, how can push it to the background? Would it be something like `terminal:~$ ./my_init_script.sh start &` ? Would this be work even if I quit from the terminal?